# how do a select data on a specific sheet for all but the first 3 rows so i can copy this into a table

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am trying to prepare the code below so that i can select all the data my main code generates (excluding  headers and titles) and copy this into a table which I then have formulas set to evaluate the file.

My current code

```
Sub tests()
 Dim lr As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")
  lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 MsgBox lr
  Set rng = ws.Range(Cells(4, 1).Address(), Cells(lr, 18).Address())
rng.Select
End Sub
```

was working for selecting when I remove the ws. portion of the code (this just selected the active sheet however).

I therefore tried adding in the rng dimension and having it in its current state but I get a 1004 error in its current state. the message box is just there as a debug tool as I'm building the code.

any suggestions as to the cause of the error would be great. also if advice could be given how i can copy this data and tell it to paste into the first cell of my first data row in my table my current though process is just select xlcopy the using tbl.DataBodyRange(1,1) and xlpastespecial values. although I am not certain this is right so guidance would be fantastic.

Comment: Remove the `.address()`? And qualify the `cells`.

Comment: Why copy an entire table when you can update the references in your formulae?

Comment: the data from my query comes from a CSV download that then gets passed through into the blank tab and the range will vary month on month. the formulas look to my reference tables that map cost centres to our edger as these rely on the sumifs xlookups etc items aren't in the csv download. As the actual monthly reporting outputs use a variety of sumifs xlookups etc it would be to complex (from other users readability) to be using counta  or offsets  to have range change and there is too much data to have the file behave manageable with whole column references. hence moving the output to a table